# Encrypting a class + serializing it

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm trying to encrypt a class before serializing it.  The only way I found is to encrypt it and return a String or a stream, is it possible to return the original class ?

```
public static Options Encrypt(Options Settings)
{
    Options sk = null;

    try
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Serialize(stream, Settings);
            byte[] data = encryptWithPadding(stream.ToArray(), 0);
            String base64EncryptedString = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
            // needs to return an option instance
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         Global.LogError("Serialization failed", e);
    }


    return sk;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to serialize such an object as part of something bigger?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yes, and also encrypt it, so that the parent class when its serialized, it should contain the encrypted member

Comment: So then a static Encrypt method isn't going to be enough, you need to do custom serialization of this type. Does protobuf-net support this?

Comment: How do you want to return instance of a class when you have already serialized and encrypted it? How will you use it after such a processing?

Comment: Send a `byte[]` over the wire. Don't try to cast it back to an `Options` object.

Comment: @EugenePodskal my idea was to give an encrypted class members then serialize it. don't know how to do it actually.

Comment: Well, you can serialize each field, encrypt it and return some Options-derived wrapper over the processed values, but how can such an instance be used after? What is the usage scenario for it?

Comment: It looks like you've done the serialization and the encryption; so... what bit isn't working? what would it mean to "return the original class" here? you have encrypted, serialized data...

Comment: You can't encrypt a class. A class is a blueprint used to create objects. You encrypt and serialize objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "encrypt" a protobuf without serializing it. Encryption generally works on bytes, not data structures. If you want to encrypt it, and then embed the encrypted version as a field in some other protobuf, make that other field have type `bytes` instead of `Options`.

(In theory you could encrypt each of the fields of `Options` individually, but this would not help you much and would very likely be less secure than encrypting the whole serialized blob.)

Comment: is it possible to explicitly call one of the callbacks like [ProtoBeforeSerialization] ? from any other classes ?